# I'm looking for a topology book

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

I'm studying engineering and I'm very interested in knowing more about topology. I've studied Calculus, so I'm not new to the subject. I was looking for a book that's not too difficult, and gives an overview of topology. That way I can know if I'd like to read more about it. What should I read?
Edit: do you think that I should study abstract algebra before topology?

Comment: Really you should study abstract algebra before moving on to topology.  You can study topology without algebra, but it's like studying statistics without calculus.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1868/list-of-generalizations-of-common-questions has a list of _five_ previous threads discussing this question and closely related questions.  I think you can study topology and abstract algebra in either order.

Answer (score 1):

Three options that I liked in my student years:

- *Outline of General Topology* by Seymour Lipschutz. Includes a good collection of solved problems.
- *General Topology* by John L. Kelley. A classic.
- *General Topology* by Stephen Willard. The most exhaustive. Includes hystorical notes.

Answer (score 0):

Kinsey's "Topology of Surfaces" is a really nice book for starting out. It's written pedagogically, and it is accessible from an undergraduate level.